# Running Script from Another Script Using os.system

Tags: python

I have two scripts, the first, mail.py, scrapes hyperlinks from emails. The second, scrape.py, scrapes data from the links using Selenium and BeautifulSoup.

I have been using `os.system('start cmd /c python scrape.py '+ link + ' && exit')` to run scrape.py when a new email with a link arrives.

Sometimes I get an error with scrape.py but when I run it by manually inserting the link it works ok.

I'm new to python and I've read that os.system can be unstable. Is that correct? Is it likely to be the cause of the problem?

I'm under time pressure to finish the project so would prefer to keep the code as is unless that is the cause.

Comment: This is an *insane* command to run.  You're telling an instance of `cmd` to run `start`, which will run `cmd` again, which will run `python`.  Why not just run `python` directly?

Comment: If at all feasible, you should refactor your code so you can simply `import` it. There are situations where it's useful or even necessary to run Python as a subprocess of itself, but this does not seem to be one of them.

Comment: Thanks guys. I did it this way in case a new email arrived whilst scrape.py was still scraping a previous email link.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to run the python script without call `cmd`:

```
os.system('python scrape.py '+ link)
```